# How to know where Optional Chaining is breaking?

Tags: swift, option-type

So in iOS Swift we can do optional chaining to simplify the `nil` checking like in the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/OptionalChaining.html)

```
let johnsAddress = Address()
johnsAddress.buildingName = "The Larches"
johnsAddress.street = "Laurel Street"
john.residence!.address = johnsAddress
if let johnsStreet = john.residence?.address?.street {
    println("John's street name is \(johnsStreet).")
} else {
    println("Unable to retrieve the address.")
}
// prints "John's street name is Laurel Street."
```

I understand about the usage of the optional chaining in `john.residence?.address?.street` but how can we know where is actually the chain is breaking (if either `residence` or `address` is `nil`). Can we determine if `residence` or `address` is `nil`, or we need to check it again with `if-else`?

Comment: The _whole point_ of optional chaining is that the value _might be `nil` at any point_. If you need to know then optional chaining is not a good candidate for your code.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Good argument! Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't do the chain then. The chain is only interesting if you *don't intend* to stop. If you do, break it up at interesting spots - otherwise, where would you put in the code for the bad cases?

```
if let residence = john.residence {
  if let address = residence.address {
    ...
  } else {
    println("missing address")
  }
} else {
  println("missing residence")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think so. Optional chaining is a convenient shortcut syntax and you are giving up a bit of control along with a couple of keypresses.

If you really need to know where exactly the chain breaks, you have to go link by link into multiple variables.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to tell where optional chaining stopped. However you can use:

```
if let johnsStreet = john.residence?.address?.street {
    println("John's street name is \(johnsStreet).")
} else if let johnAddress = john.residence?.address {
    println("Unable to retreive street, but John's address is \(johnAddress).")
} else {
    println("Unable to retrieve the address.")
}
```