# Why does Swift's optional binding succeed with 'nil' in certain cases?

Tags: if-statement, swift, option-type

Apple's [Swift language documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TheBasics.html) says that *optional binding* (a.k.a. `if let`) will "check for a value *inside* an optional" and "*extract* that value into" a variable or constant). But this doesn't match what I'm seeing. For example

```
var x: Int? = nil

if let y1: Int? = x {
    println("y1 = \(y1)") // This is printed, suggesting that x is not checked "inside", but left as Optional(nil) (!= nil)
}

if let y2: Int? = x? {
    println("y2 = \(y2)")
}

if let y3: Int = x? {
    println("y3 = \(y3)")
}

if let y4: Int = x {
    println("y4 = \(y4)")
}

if let y5 = x? {
    println("y5 = \(y5)")
}

if let y6 = x {
    println("y6 = \(y6)")
}
```

results in (only)

```
"y1 = nil"
```

suggesting that no checking "inside" of `x` is taking place in the `y1` case (and that `x` is left as a wrapped `nil`, which is not equal to unwrapped `nil`). The `y2` case seems to confirm this by forcing a "check inside" (or is that just *optional chaining* "taking over"); but there must be more to the story since the `y4` and `y6` cases also do not print and thus behave as if a "check inside" is happening.

I suspect that there's some insight to be gained from trying

```
"x = 42"
```

which results in

```
"y1 = Optional(42)"
"y2 = Optional(42)"
"y3 = 42"
"y4 = 42"
"y5 = 42"
"y6 = 42"
```

but if three's some there, it's lost on me.

It seems like (1) the "optional" on the right side of the expression does indeed get "checked inside" if an explicit check is asked for (with `?`); but otherwise (2) the left hand side of the expression influences how far "inside" a check is performed (just far enough to make a valid assignment).

How is optional binding working in each of these cases? In particular, when `x == nil` why  does `y1` print, and given that it does, why don't `y4` and `y6` (or generate assignment errors)?

Answer (score 2):

I interpret this differently:

```
var x: Int? = 1

if let y1: Int = x {
    println("y1 = \(y1)") 
}

//prints y = 1, the optional was checked, contains a value and passes it

var x: Int? = nil

if let y1: Int = x {
    println("y1 = \(y1)") 
}

//does not execute because x does not contain value that can be passed to a non optional y

var x: Int? = nil

if let y1: Int? = x {
    println("y1 = \(y1)")
}
// y = nil, since y is optional and can hold a value of x which is nil, then it passes nil
```

Optional binding is for checking if an optional contains a value to pass to a non optional parameter.

Comment: So is it like this: The right hand side gets checked for "optional chaining" first (which is where the first `y2`, `y3`, and `y5` cases end). Then, if that's not `nil` then things proceed if a valid assignment can be made. It's that simple?

Comment: yes, if anywhere along the chain, it is nil, the binding will fail.  If you need to know where the binding failed, there is a good discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524246/how-to-know-where-optional-chaining-is-breaking

Comment: So: In cases `y2`, `y3` and `y5` optional *chaining* hits a `nil` and things end. In cases `y4`, and `y6` a check inside of `x` is made, and `nil` is found (and cannot be assigned to a non-optional) so things end. But I'm still confused about exactly what's happening with `y1`: it seems like no "check inside" is happening here. If there was, things would fail (e.g. `if let y1: Int? = nil { ...}` fails). It seems like the "check inside" happens *as necessary to get the assignment to work*.

Comment: I think there is confusion around the syntax x? when x originally is an optional.  I would have never thought to try that syntax.  I interpret this as {nil} or some nil.  Which in assignment declarations is apparently not treated the same as nil itself even if it prints as nil in a playground.  Anyways, a clever problem you posed.

Comment: I think you're being generous: I'm not sure "there is" confusion; it may just be *me* that's confused. It's certainly a contrived example, but I'd assumed it's just like any other optional chaining expression, `x?.something`, except that "something" is identity — i.e. it does nothing, so if what's "inside" `x` isn't `nil` the expression is re-wrapped as usual (since the expression could be `nil` and must this be optional).

Comment: If that's right then I understand what's happening on all the right hand sides; and what's confusing me here is that the "look inside" of the right hand side (after any optional chaining or other messing with `?` there) happens *only* if needed to attempt a valid assignment (e.g., from an optional to a non-optional). Hence, in the `y1` case, there's no looking inside, because assigning an `Int?` to and `Int?` works; while `x2` tripped up on optional chaining (it encountered `nil`).

Comment: What confused me is the documentation,which makes it seem like the look inside always happens. That is that the right hand side is always unwrapped, which it clearly isn't, otherwise `y1` would behave like `if let y1: Int? = nil { ...}` (unless there's something else going on).

Answer (score 1):

You assigned an optional Int to an optional Int. The assignment did succeed. It will always succeed, whether the optional Int contained an Int or not.

Comment: So no "check inside" happens in that case (`y1`). Such checks seem only to actually happen when needed to make the assignment work (cases `y4` and `y6`, as revealed when `x` is non-`nil`). Right?

Comment: The crux here (for me) is why `let y1: Int? = nil { ...}` behaves differently from `let y1: Int? = x { ...}` where `x` is `nil`. (See discussion on [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26576451/656912)).