# Optional binding of nil literal vs. variable that is nil in Swift

Tags: swift, syntax, variable-assignment, conditional-statements, option-type

In Swift, why does

```
var x: Int? = nil
if let y: Int? = x { ... }
```

behave differently from

```
if let y: Int? = nil { ... }
```

My [understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26576556/656912) of why the first case succeeds suggests that the second should as well, so I must not really be understanding.

The latter is not failing because of an invalid assignment, nor because of optional chaining; and otherwise it seems the same as the former. Why does the latter fail, and how is it different from the former. Exactly at what point, and for what reason, is the second optional binding abandoned?

Comment: Related: [How do Generators whose Element is Optional know when they've reached the end?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36253204/2792531)

Answer (score 9):

```
if let y: Int? = nil { ... }
```

is equivalent to

```
if let y: Int? = nil as Int?? { ... }
```

is equivalent to

```
if let y: Optional<Int> = Optional<Optional<Int>>() { ... }
```

This tries to cast `Optional<Optional<Int>>` to `Optional<Int>`, and it fails because `Optional<Optional<Int>>()` does not contains `Optional<Int>` value.

---

Oneliner equivalent to

```
var x: Int? = nil
if let y: Int? = x { ... }
```

is

```
if let y: Int? = nil as Int? { ... }
```

---

ADDED:

As I answered on [What does Swift's optional binding do to the type it's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615711/what-does-swifts-optional-binding-do-to-the-type-its-arguments).

```
if let y: Int? = nil as Int? { ... }
```

is compiled as:

```
if let y:Int? = nil as Int? as Int?? { ... }
```

Here, we should mind that `nil as Int? as Int??` is **not** equivalent to `nil as Int??`.
The former is `Optional(Optional<Int>())`, but the latter is `Optional<Optional<Int>>()`.

With this in mind, I think,

> So the optional binding in my first example (does indeed) "check inside" and finds nil, which is perfectly valid to assign to Int?; but my second checks and finds Optional(nil), which can't be assigned to Int?

The first example "check inside" of `Int??` and just finds `Optional<Int>()` value that is `Int?` type which can be assigned to `Int?`; But the second one finds *nothing* to be assigned and fails.

Comment: This is very insightful -- your last example makes a connection between unwrapping Optionals via optional binding and optionally bound casts like `if cell = tableViewCell as? MyTableViewCell`. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, very interesting! So the optional binding in my first example (does indeed) ["check inside"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26576366/656912) and finds `nil`, which is perfectly valid to assign to `Int?`; but my second checks and finds `Optional(nil)`, which can't be assigned to `Int?`. Is that right?

Comment: And if that is right: [Why is](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26615711/656912) `if let y: Int? = nil { ... }` the same as `if let y: Int? = nil as Int?? { ... }` — especially when (outside of `if`) `let y: Int? = nil` is a valid assignment?

Answer (score 1):

`let` [declares a constant](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_572) that is set at initialization time. Using the `let` in an `if` statement with an `Optional<T>`, then it binds the initialized constant the the result of a *failable* initializer, not literally to `nil` or another literal.

The compiler allowed you to use `nil` directly, instead of '4' for e.g., since `nil` has use/context outside of Optional; however, this literal use of `nil` bypasses the initializer, so there is no result to bind to. In the cases of 4 or Int(4), the compiler knows something is awry and won't compile.

Review the following example:

```
var xnil: Int? = nil
var x4: Int? = Int?(4)
var xnone: Int? = Int?()
var xdefault: Int? = Int()

if let znil: Int? = nil {
    println("znil:\(znil)")
} else {
    println("znil: did not bind")
}

if let zn0: Int? = Int?(nilLiteral: ()) {
    println("zn0:\(zn0)")
}

if let zn1: Int? = Int?(()) {
    println("zn1:\(zn1)")
}

if let zn2: Int? = Int?() {
    println("zn1:\(zn2)")
}

if let zn3: Int? = Int?.None {
    println("zn3:\(zn3)")
}

if Int?.None == nil {
    println(".None == nil")
}

if let zo0: Int? = Int?(4) {
    println("zo0:\(zo0)")
}

//nil-test.swift:36:20: error: bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type
//if let zo1: Int? = 4 {
//                   ^
/*
if let zo1: Int? = 4 {
    println("zo1:\(zo1)")
}
*/

//nil-test.swift:51:20: error: bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type
//if let zo2: Int? = Int(4) {
//                   ^
/*
if let zo2: Int? = Int(4) {
    println("zo2:\(zo2)")
}
*/


if let zxn0: Int? = xnil {
    println("zxn0:\(zxn0)")
}

if let zxn1: Int? = x4 {
    println("zxn1:\(zxn1)")
}

if let zxn2: Int? = xnone {
    println("zxn2:\(zxn2)")
}

if let zxn3: Int? = xdefault {
    println("zxn3:\(zxn3)")
}
```

... it outputs:

```
znil: did not bind
zn0:nil
zn1:nil
zn1:nil
zn3:nil
.None == nil
zo0:Optional(4)
zxn0:nil
zxn1:Optional(4)
zxn2:nil
zxn3:Optional(0)
```

*UPDATE*: Explaining the difference between `Type` and `Type?`.

See this example:

```
if let a: Int? = nil {
    println("a: \(a)")
} else { 
    println("a: let fail")
}

if let b1: Int? = Int?(nilLiteral: ()) { // same as Int?() -- added nilLiteral to be explicit here
    println("b1: \(b1)")
}

if let b2: Int? = Int?(44) {
    println("b2: \(b2); b2!: \(b2!)")
}

if let c1: Int = Int?(44) {
    println("c1: \(c1)")
}

if let c2: Int = Int?(nilLiteral: ()) { // Again, Int?() would suffice
    println("c2: \(c2)")
} else {
    println("c2: let fail")
}

/// NOTE: these 'd' examples represents a more idiomatic form
var m: Int? = Int?()
if let d1 = m {
    println("d1: \(d1)")
} else {
    println("d1: let fail")
}

m = Int?(444)
if let d2 = m {
    println("d2: \(d2)")
} else {
    println("d2: let fail")
}

m = Int?()
println("m?: \(m?)")
if let whyDoThis: Int? = m {
    println("whyDoThis?: \(whyDoThis?) -- the `let` is telling you nothing about 'm!'")
}
```

... it outputs:

```
a: let fail
b1: nil
b2: Optional(44); b2!: 44
c1: 44
c2: let fail
d1: let fail
d2: 444
m?: nil
whyDoThis?: nil -- the `let` is telling you nothing about 'm!'!
```

... so, ask yourself:

- Why did `a` fail, and `b1` bind successfully, even though it contains a nil value?
- Why does `if let whyDoThis ...` succeed when `m` clearly contains a nil value at that point?
- And what does the value of `whyDoThis?` tell you about `m!`?

In the end, idiomatic Swift pseudocode, for this case, should look like the following:

```
var maybeT: MyType?
// ... maybe set maybeT to a MyType, maybe not
if let reallyHaveT = maybeT {
  // reallyHaveT has a bound value of type MyType
}
```

UPDATE 2: Okay, let's look at types ...

See the following example:

```
var none: Int? = Int?()
var one: Int? = Int?(1)

println("Int()   type: \(_stdlib_getTypeName(Int())), val: \(Int())")
println("Int(1)  type: \(_stdlib_getTypeName(Int(1))), val: \(Int(1))")
println("Int?()  type: \(_stdlib_getTypeName(Int?())), val: \(Int?())")
println("Int?(1) type: \(_stdlib_getTypeName(Int?(1))), val: \(Int?(1))")
println("none    type: \(_stdlib_getTypeName(none)), val: \(none)")
println("one     type: \(_stdlib_getTypeName(one)), val: \(one)")

if let x = none {
    println("`let x = none`       x type: \(_stdlib_getTypeName(x))")
} else {
    println("`let x = none`       FAIL")
}
if let x: Int = none {
    println("`let x: Int = none`  x type: \(_stdlib_getTypeName(x))")
} else {
    println("`let x: Int = none`  FAIL")
}
if let x: Int? = none {
    println("`let x: Int? = none` x type: \(_stdlib_getTypeName(x))")
}

if let y = one {
    println("`let y = one`        y type: \(_stdlib_getTypeName(y))")
}
if let y: Int = one {
    println("`let y: Int = one`   y type: \(_stdlib_getTypeName(y))")
}
if let y: Int? = one {
    println("`let y: Int? = one`  y type: \(_stdlib_getTypeName(y))")
}

if let z: Int? = nil {
    println("`let z: Int? = nil`  z type: \(_stdlib_getTypeName(z))")
} else {
    println("`let z: Int? = nil`  FAIL")
}
if let z = Int?() {
    println("`let z = Int?()`     z type: \(_stdlib_getTypeName(z))")
} else {
    println("`let z = Int?()`     FAIL")
}
```

... it outputs:

```
Int()   type: _TtSi, val: 0
Int(1)  type: _TtSi, val: 1
Int?()  type: _TtSq, val: nil
Int?(1) type: _TtSq, val: Optional(1)
none    type: _TtSq, val: nil
one     type: _TtSq, val: Optional(1)
`let x = none`       FAIL
`let x: Int = none`  FAIL
`let x: Int? = none` x type: _TtSq
`let y = one`        y type: _TtSi
`let y: Int = one`   y type: _TtSi
`let y: Int? = one`  y type: _TtSq
`let z: Int? = nil`  FAIL
`let z = Int?()`     FAIL
```

The point I want to stress is that you are effectively invoking `let z = Int?()` when you write `let z: Int? = nil`. This will fail to bind when used in an `if` statement. Always.

Comment: But why is `if let y: Int? = nil { ... }` [the same as](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26614198/656912) `if let y: Int? = nil as Int?? { ... }` — especially when (outside of `if`) `let y: Int? = nil` is a valid assignment?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius They're "the same as" each other insofar as the nil assignment causes the data in the variable container to be set to `nil`, and therefore make the `let` fail-through? It doesn't matter which way you typecast `nil` -- it's just `nil`. `Optional<T>` stores `None` or `Some(T)` -- if you assign `nil` to `Optional<T>`, you basically end up with `Optional<T>.None`.

Comment: So they're the same or not? That assertion is the core of the @rintaro [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26614198/656912).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius added more info the help explain the differences in binding during a `if let ...`.

Comment: Yes: Those three questions are exactly the ones I'm trying to answer. Especially the first 2. But what are the answers?!

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I was trying to lead you to the answer/s. ;-) When you declare the type you are binding manually, to mimic the idiomatic `if let x = maybeX { ...` style, you would write `if let x: Type = maybeX { ...`. If you write `if let x: Type? = maybeX { ...` then you are declaring that you want to bind *an optional value* -- this is different than the short idiomatic form which "extracts" the value if it is set, and will not if it is a nil convertible type.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius `if let x: Type? = maybeX { ...` has very little practical use and differs greatly from the idiomatic form. In fact, it will always succeed, whereas the idiomatic form is designed to offer some type safety and "fail in place" so that we write constructs like `if (x != nil) { NSObject *y = x; ...` less often.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius added yet another example, stressing types

Answer (score 0):

`if let` is used to get rid of the optional. If you want to see when the variable is nil use

```
if let y: Int = x {
// This occurs if you are able to give a non-nil value to the variable
} else {
// This occurs if the optional x is nil
}
```

as far as I know you shouldn't try declare the type of a constant in the `if let` statement to be optional because that kind of defeats the purpose of the if let statement.