# What does Swift's optional binding do to the type it's arguments?

Tags: if-statement, swift, syntax, assignment-operator, option-type

Why is

```
if let y: Int? = nil { ... }
```

[the same as](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26614198/656912)

```
if let y: Int? = nil as Int?? { ... }
```

(and thus an invalid assignment) especially when, on its own

```
let y: Int? = nil
```

is not the same as

```
let y: Int? = nil as Int??
```

(since `let y: Int? = nil` is a valid assignment)?

Comment: I think you're starting to veer off into territory that would be handled much better on [Apple's Swift dev forum](https://devforums.apple.com/community/tools/languages/swift). The actual Swift team answers questions there, so you'll be able to get more definitive answers and have a back and forth to get the details of this.

Comment: @NateCook: Not sure where why. Can you explain? This seems no different from any other question here: I need to know what's going on so I can avoid coding errors.

Comment: I'm not saying you *shouldn't* ask here, just that you'll probably have better luck in the dev forums (or on #swiftlang, honestly). It seems more like you're exploring the fringes of how optionals and optional binding works than actually dealing with writing code; `if let y: Int? = nil { }` completely misses the point of optional binding, so I don't see how this is a problem you're actually running into.

Comment: @NateCook: I thought would reveal something about how optional binding was working. Since it seems central to [understanding why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26614198/656912) `var x: Int? = nil; if let y: Int? = x { ... }` [works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26576556/656912). It's the key that unlocks both those other questions. Otherwise none of it make much sense (for me anyway). I also thought it would be the right place for @rintaro to explain where [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26614198/656912) came from.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Swift's optional binding succeed with 'nil' in certain cases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576366/why-does-swifts-optional-binding-succeed-with-nil-in-certain-cases)

Comment: @SteveRosenberg: Actually it's crucial to figuring out what's going in in that question. The answer there assumes this, but this ins't explained there.

Comment: Okay, didn't realize.

Comment: Have you posted this over at the Apple Dev forums?  Likely you are deep into the inner workings of Swift here and need the Apple team to respond definitively.

Comment: @SteveRosenberg: Good idea. I'm curious about that too. Mostly here the question is what the I see coding (since it's not what I expect and seemed arbitrary). I think [rintaro's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26624338/656912) has cleared it up though.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I will answer, with my poor English skills ;-)

Let's start with this:

```
if let lvalue:T = rvalue { ... }
```

At first the compiler tries to convert `rvalue` to `T?` by wrapping with `Optional`. For example:

```
typealias T = Int
let rvalue:Int? = 1
if let lvalue:T = rvalue { ... } // do nothing because `rvalue` is already `T?`

//---

typealias T = Int??
let rvalue:Int = 1
if let lvalue:T = rvalue { ... } // rvalue will be converted to `T?`, that is `Int???`

//---

typealias T = Int
let rvalue:Int?? = 1
if let lvalue:T = rvalue { ... } // error because `rvalue` could not be converted by wrapping with Optional
```

Then the runtime look into *converted* `rvalue` by unwrapping **once** whether that value is `nil` or not. If not `nil` then assign and success.

This is the rule for `if let lvalue:T = rvalue { ... }`

---

On the other hand,

```
let lvalue:T = rvalue
```

It's similar but not the same. The compiler tries to convert `rvalue` to `T`, not `T?`.

```
typealias T = Int??
let rvalue:Int?? = 1
let lvalue:T = rvalue // Do nothing because `rvalue` is `T`

//---

typealias T = Int??
let rvalue:Int = 1
let lvalue:T = rvalue // rvalue will be converted to `T`, that is `Int??`
```

Then the runtime can unconditionally assign `rvalue` to `lvalue`.

I think this is the difference.

---

You you want to observe these compiler works, you can use `swiftc -dump-ast` command.

```
$ cat test.swift
let i:Int? = 1
if let y:Int? = i { }

$ xcrun swiftc -dump-ast test.swift
(source_file
  (top_level_code_decl
    (brace_stmt
      (pattern_binding_decl
        (pattern_typed type='Int?'
          (pattern_named type='Int?' 'i')
)
        (inject_into_optional implicit type='Int?' location=test.swift:1:14 range=[test.swift:1:14 - line:1:14]
          (call_expr implicit type='Int' location=test.swift:1:14 range=[test.swift:1:14 - line:1:14]
            (constructor_ref_call_expr implicit type='(_builtinIntegerLiteral: Int2048) -> Int' location=test.swift:1:14 range=[test.swift:1:14 - line:1:14]
              (declref_expr implicit type='Int.Type -> (_builtinIntegerLiteral: Int2048) -> Int' location=test.swift:1:14 range=[test.swift:1:14 - line:1:14] decl=Swift.(file).Int.init(_builtinIntegerLiteral:) specialized=no)
              (type_expr implicit type='Int.Type' location=test.swift:1:14 range=[test.swift:1:14 - line:1:14] typerepr='<<IMPLICIT>>'))
            (tuple_expr implicit type='(_builtinIntegerLiteral: Int2048)' location=test.swift:1:14 range=[test.swift:1:14 - line:1:14] names=_builtinIntegerLiteral
              (integer_literal_expr type='Int2048' location=test.swift:1:14 range=[test.swift:1:14 - line:1:14] value=1)))))
)
  (var_decl "i" type='Int?' access=internal let storage_kind='stored')
  (top_level_code_decl
    (brace_stmt
      (if_stmt
        (pattern_binding_decl
          (pattern_typed type='Int?'
            (pattern_named type='Int?' 'y')
)
          (inject_into_optional implicit type='Int??' location=test.swift:2:17 range=[test.swift:2:17 - line:2:17]
            (declref_expr type='Int?' location=test.swift:2:17 range=[test.swift:2:17 - line:2:17] decl=test.(file).i@test.swift:1:5 specialized=no)))

        (brace_stmt))))
```

Comment: Thanks! So in conditional binding, `rvalue` is *first* and *always* wrapped in `Optional`; and only then unwrapped once to see if assignment works? And in (regular) assignment, it is there is no wrapping (of course) and `rvalue` is just checked to see if it can be converted to the type of `lvalue`?

Comment: Yes I think so. IMO, you should check that out with `swiftc -dump-ast`. You can see when and how the compiler inserts `inject_into_optional`s.

Comment: Hmmm. So if the steps really are 1: Optional binding, if any (stop on `nil` otherwise evaluate and wrap in Optional); 2: Wrap (again, always?); 3: Find what's "inside" (==unwrap?); 4: Attempt assignment of result, then I understand the above, but I don't understand what's happening with `if let y3: Int = x1? {...}` or `if let y4: Int = x1 { ... }`, if we've done `x1 = 42`. These [seem to end up](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26576366/656912) at step 4 with `Optional(42)` which can't be assigned? Do I not have the steps right? Are they not all always performed?

Comment: Maybe step 2 (the wrapping you explain) only happens if `rvalue` is *not* and optional binding expression (but still happens even when it is already of optional type)?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not English native. It's very hard to discuss in English for me.

Comment: That's OK: anything helps! The question seems to boil down to: When is wrapping added to `rvalue`, and at what point?

Answer (score 1):

Think about what optional binding is for. It allows you to take an optional value, and condition on whether it is `nil` or not, and if it is not `nil`, to unwrap the contained value and bind it to a variable. So it is like this:

```
if let non_optional_var = optional_expr {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Thus if `optional_expr` has type `T?`, then `non_optional_var` has type `T`. (When I wrote "non_optional_var" I didn't mean literally that it can't be optional, but to express that it has one less level of optional-ness than the "optional_expr". Thus, if `non_optional_var` is type `Int?`, then `optional_expr` has type `Int??`.

By the way, the optional binding syntax is syntactic sugar for switching on the `Optional` enum:

```
switch optional_expr {
case .Some(let non_optional_var):
    ...
case .None:
    ...
}
```